# SSIS Always run a specific step last without connecting to every parent

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package with about 50 different steps. Many of the steps will run in parallel.

I would like to put a ScriptTask at the end of the package such that, regardless of success or failure, I send out an email which reports on the status of the package run (the package logs things to a database as it runs, so the ScriptTask involves querying the status tables and formatting them into HTML).

Is there a way to have a task that executes when all other tasks have either completed running, or been skipped due to dependencies?

I have tried to add my task to the OnError event handler, but this has it raise up to n times when tasks fail in parallel. I don't want to have every single step flow to the ScriptTask with the OnFailure condition, because it will make the package functionally impossible to use due to the volume of connections. I also believe that connecting it as such would not ensure it ran, as some steps would be skipped and thus not have a success or failure status.

Answer (score 1):

I can do this in two different ways

1. Add a Sequence Container to your Control Flow.
2. Move all existing Tasks inside of the the Sequence Container
3. Add your Script Task outside the Sequence Container. Change the Precedence constraint from Success to Completion by double clicking on the line

Option b

1. Create an package that has your script task in it.
2. Create a master package that runs the original package and then calls the package with the script task, passing any variables as needed for it to generate the email.

Comment: The sequence container with the entire package inside is an interesting idea - i'll give that a whirl tonight.